# Composite Foreign Key in SQLAlchemey allowing references to non-existent records

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a database with a concept of points and objects. Objects are associated with a single point in a one-to-one relationship. Only 1 object can be associated with a point at a time, which I have enforced through a uniqueness constraint.

However, I always want to say that objects can only be associated with Points that exist, but I'm struggling to see how to achieve that.

Before I explain further, here is some test code that I have:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
import sqlalchemy.orm as sqlorm
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import os

debug = True
db_file = "/".join([os.getcwd() if __name__ == "__main__" else os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sqlite.db'])

engine_opts = {
    'echo': debug
}

engine = sql.create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(db_file), **engine_opts)
Session = sqlorm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()


class Point(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'point'
    x = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    y = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "({x},{y})".format(x=self.x, y=self.y)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Obj(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'obj'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = sql.Column(sql.Integer)
    y = sql.Column(sql.Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
        sql.ForeignKeyConstraint([x, y], [Point.x, Point.y]),
        sql.UniqueConstraint(x, y, name='obj_coords'),
    )
    point = sqlorm.relationship("Point", backref=sqlorm.backref('obj', uselist=False))


def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session()

    min_val = 0
    max_val = 20

    for x in range(min_val, max_val):
        for y in range(min_val, max_val):
            session.add(Point(x=x, y=y))
    session.commit()

    session.add(Obj(x=0, y=0))
    session.add(Obj(x=10, y= 10))
    session.add(Obj(x=-1, y=-1))

    session.commit()
    session.close()


def reinit_db():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    init_db()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reinit_db()
```

I have a composite primary key for `Point`, and I'd like to use `x` and `y` on `Obj` as a foreign key.

The `backref` works and the uniqueness constraint means no 2 objs can occupy the same point, but my test code allows me to create an `Obj` in the non-existent `Point` (-1, -1) when I want that to be prevented.

Is this possible to achieve, and how might I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really using SQLite, not only for demonstration purposes, the problem is that it currently does not enforce foreign key constraints by default (and prior to 3.6.19 did not enforce them at all). You have to execute `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` before starting any transactions. In SQLAlchemy this can be implemented using event system:

```
import sqlalchemy.event as sqlevent

# ...

engine = sql.create_engine('sqlite:///{0}'.format(db_file), **engine_opts)
sqlevent.listen(engine, 'connect',
    lambda conn, rec: conn.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;'))
```

Then executing your program produces an integrity error, as required:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError)
foreign key constraint failed u'INSERT INTO obj (x, y) VALUES (?, ?)' (-1, -1)
```

Note that this error is only raised at flush/commit time: it is reported by the database engine, and SQLAlchemy has no way to know you've created an invalid object: it doesn't track FKs on Python side.

Comment: That sorted it, perfect! And yes, I'm developing on SQLite at the moment, just for convenience, although I'm starting to question if it is all that convenient if there's 'gotchas' like this